# What does the Automatic (Desktop vs Mobile) setting in the Kindle Fire Browser look for at a website?

Tags: browser, mobile, kindle-fire

The Kindle Fire browser has a Desktop or Mobile view mode setting, and the 3 choices are:

- Automatic: Optimize for each website
- Desktop: Optimize for desktop view
- Mobile: Optimize for mobile view

My question is, when it's set to Automatic, what exactly is it looking for/keying off of on each website, to decide if it's a desktop optimized site or a mobile optimized site.  I'm asking because I'd like to force it into one mode if a user has their Kindle set to Automatic.

Comment: I believe the information ab the site type is in the header that you get back when trying to load a website

Comment: In the response header?  I can't find anything in the standard fields that would be used to indicate that.  If it's keying off a non-standard field (like X-Powered-By for example), I can easily set that, but I don't know what the field is that I need to set.

Comment: In retrospect, it doesn't make sense that it would be anything in the response header.  The fire sends a different useragent if it's in desktop mode vs. mobile mode.  So it stands to reason that in Automatic, it somehow is deciding which useragent to send ahead of time.  I don't get how that would work though.  I'd really love to know what the Automatic setting is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume automatic is per-request.  As you can imagine, Silk can figure out the most popular sites like every other mobile device manufacturer does.  Then in the background Silk does A/B testing in order of the most popular sites to see if there is a difference.  If there is, then the Silk team uses some proprietary techniques to decide which one is better for the Fire.  For example, if the desktop site is full of Flash, then mobile is the obvious better choice.  If the mobile site is less functional than the desktop site and the desktop site looks fine, then (based on judgement) the desktop site is better.

There is nothing you can do as a developer to force one or the other because, as you can imagine, that would allow developers to override what should be a user setting.

So, my best advice is to make your site like normal.  If you want Fire users to use the desktop site then provide that behavior by sniffing out user-agent strings.

Does that provide clarity?